# Where does Eclipse manage workspace information?

Tags: java, eclipse

Background: I've created a clone of an Eclipse Java project, renamed some folders and some identifiers, and tried to import it to integrate it into my Eclipse workspace. The result: Autodetection of project aspects surprisingly did not work as expected.

I compared all kinds of Eclipse files beween these two projects and can not see any real difference. Furthermore I don't find any information Eclipse would store in these projects beyond very basic project aspects. However, there MUST be a place where Eclipse stores information as there apparantly EXIST difference settings for both projects.

So my question is: Where does Eclipse store information about projects in a workspace?

I know this question has been asked before, but the answers are quite old and therefore wrong for current Eclipse installations. That's why I ask this question again.

---

Update:
User greg-449 is perfectly right. In contrary to my statement the storage location has *not* changed. In consequence this means that this question *is* redundant to the existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is still stored in the `.metadata` directory.

The location of that directory is taken from the `osgi.instance.area` system property.

You can check the value of `osgi.instance.area` in the 'Installation Details' dialog on the 'Configuration' tab (use 'Help > About' to open the installation details dialog)